# How to find the K-th thinnest paths in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the K-th thinnest paths in a directed graph (like Yen's algorithm for shortest paths).
By "thinnest" I mean with the lowest weight per edge.

For example, in this following graph:
[image: example graph]

The algortihm should return (in order, thinnest to thickest):

- A - B - C - E - x
- A - B - D - E - x
- A - F - x
- A - x
- A - G - x

Comment: How exactly is a "thinnest path" defined? As far as I understand your example, for a directed acyclic graph one calls a path $P = p_o, p_1, \dotsc, p_m$ thinner than another path $Q = q_0, q_1, \dotsc, q_n$ if there exists some initial subpath $S = s_0, s_1, \dotsc, s_k$ with edges $s_i = p_i = q_i$ for all $i = 1, \dotsc, k$, and the weight of edge $p_{k+1}$ is smaller than the weight of $q_{k+1}$.

Comment: If this is the case and you wish to enumerate all paths in order of thinness, a depth-first search that picks the edge of smallest weight at each depth will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my example. The algorithm mustn't always follow the lowest edge.
I'm working on a function to compare two different paths.